# errors when trying to get the value of a variable in another view

Tags: ios

please i got errors when i try to read the content of a variable in view2 which was initialized in view1, i explain :

view1 is named **RechercherViewController**

view2 is named **StationsSurLaCarteViewController**

**RechercherViewController.h :**

```
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *typeCarburantChoisi;
```

**RechercherViewController.m :**

```
@synthesize typeCarburantChoisi;
```

**StationsSurLaCarteViewController.h**

```
#import "RechercherViewController.h"

@interface StationsSurLaCarteViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet AideStationsSurLaCarteViewController *aideStationsSurLaCarteViewController;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textField;

}
@end
```

**StationsSurLaCarteViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    textField.text=RechercherViewController.typeCarburantChoisi;
}
```

when building the app, i got actually two errors :

```
error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'StationsSurLaCarteViewController'
```

and

```
error: accessing unknown 'typeCarburantChoisi' class method
```

thx for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have defined an **instance** property `typeCarburantChoisi` but in your `StationsSurLaCarteViewController.m` code you are trying to access kind of a **class** property (btw, there is no such thing in Objective-C). You will instead need a reference to your `RechercherViewController` instance and ask it for the property – this will resolve the second compiler error.

Regarding the first error I am not really sure what happened here. Maybe you have an error in your `RechercherViewController.h` file?
In any case, you should rather not import the interface file into `StationsSurLaCarteViewController.h`. Instead, use

```
@class RechercherViewController;
```

and import the full declaration in your implementation file `StationsSurLaCarteViewController.m` only.

Also, did you mix up `AideStationsSurLaCarteViewController` and `RechercherViewController` in your example?